# async I/O with neighbor solicitations on Linux

Tags: networking, network-programming, ipv6, icmpv6

I am implementing neighbor solicitation using asynchronous I/O with poll on Linux. My host has multiple interfaces (and no default route). Since neither the socket API nor libnetlink offer a way to perform neighbor discovery on request, I'm implementing it myself.

My set of next hop IPv6 addresses comes from the local routing table (about 100 next hops). The neighbor cache only has about 30 to 80 cached at a time and I can't rely on the hardware address of the next hop to be available there.

*Problem:* When sending out solicitations as fast as async I/O allows, I receive only one or no responses.

*Details:* For each interface, I create a socket (`socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6)`), perform a range of configuration (`FD_CLOEXEC`, nonblocking, `ICMP6_FILTER`, `SO_DONTROUTE`, `IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS`, `IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS`, `IPV6_RECVHOPLIMIT`) and bind it to the address of the interface.

In a typical fashion, I'm running a poll loop and send out solicitations when I can write and receive packets when I can read. Here is the weird behavior:

1. If I run the code with a *single* neighbor addresses everything works as expected.
2. If I run the code with *multiple* neighbor addresses and wait for a matching advertisement before sending a new solicitation, the code works.
3. **But**, if I send out multiple solicitations without waiting for the respective advertisements, I get one or (mostly) no advertisements matching my solicitations.

In all cases my program receives advertisements that are not responses to my requests. As a result I'm confident that receiving generally works in all three cases.

To ensure that this is not corrupted state and to verify that the packets are actually send out, I recorded the solicitations with Wireshark. The packets that solicit an advertisement are identical to packets that don't solicit an advertisement. (I extracted the bytes of both packets and ran them through `diff`.) One capture has a reply while the other one does not.

(I checked the source code of `ndisc6`, which does use `poll` as well, but only sends out one solicitation at once.)

Edit: Added information on query set. See comment below.

Comment: For a standard IPv6 `/64` network, there are 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible host addresses, and at 1,000,000 addresses per second (unlikely), it would take over 584,542 years to test every address.

Comment: I'm not trying to test every address. Sorry for the confusion. I have a routing table with about ~100 different next hop addresses. libnetlink allows me to read it at runtime. However, the neighbor table only holds a varying number between 30 and 80 of those addresses and I cannot reliably query the hardware address of my next hop from it.